# OpenSSH client refuses to use a new key file

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, public-key-encryption, private-key

After generating a new ssh private key (`id_rsa`) on one server and distributing it across a server network, one server is failing to use the new key, and falls back to password authentication instead.

Copying the id_rsa to a new file and using it instead works.

```
$ ssh -i id_rsa user@server
user@server's password:
$ cp id_rsa id_rsa.copy
$ chmod --reference=id_rsa id_rsa.copy
$ ssh -i id_rsa.copy user@server
Last login: Wed Apr  2 06:30:36 2014 from otherhost
[user@server ~]$
```

Running `ssh -vvv` debug:

**id_rsa:**

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa.
...
debug1: identity file id_rsa type 1
...
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

**id_rsa.copy:**

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa.copy.
...
debug1: identity file id_rsa.copy type -1
...
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa.copy
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

So for some reason OpenSSH is handling the key files differently. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server that experienced the problem had *both* `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` key files copied before. While copying the new key files I only overwrote `id_rsa` leaving `id_rsa.pub` in place. This caused ssh to use `id_rsa` incorrectly.

**Removing `id_rsa.pub` or updating it with the correct version** solved the problem.